# Combine explicit keyword arguments and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

In Python, I can explicitly list the keyword-only parameters that a function accepts:

```py
def foo(arg, *, option_a=False, option_b=False):
    return another_fn(arg, option_a=option_a, option_b=option_b)
```

While the syntax to call the other function is a bit verbose, I do get nice autocomplete on the named arguments in a function call:

[image: Autocomplete on named arguments in vscode]

I can eliminate the redundancy in the function call by using `**kwargs`:

```py
def foo(arg, **kwargs):
    return another_fn(arg, **kargs)
```

But then I lose the autocomplete in my editor (and have a much less clear function signature):

[image: No autocomplete with kwargs]

How can I get the best of both worlds? I'd like to write an explicit function signature, but still get a `kwargs` dict in the function body.

Comment: It's best to use `**kwargs` when there are arbitary number of keywords args you want to pass to a function. In your case you have only two keyword arguments to pass. So, use `option_a=False, option_b=True` which is more clear in this case.

Comment: @Ch3steR suppose I have ten keyword arguments and need to pass all of them to another function which takes the same keyword arguments. You can see how the boilerplate expands w/o `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible use scenario for [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#locals):

```py
def foo(arg, arg2=None):
    return another_fn(**locals())
```

If you need to, you can also unpack `self`:

```py
class bar:
    def foo(self, arg):
        kwargs = locals()
        kwargs.pop('self')
        return another_fn(**kwargs)
```

Caveat: if you define any local variables in the method before you call `locals()`, they'll end up in the output and you'll have to filter them out.

```py
def foo(self, arg=None):
    baz = 'Oops'
    kwargs = locals() # {'self': <bar at 0x0000>, 'arg': None, 'baz': 'Oops'}
    return another_fn(**kwargs)
```

The simple solution is to just call `locals()` before you do anything else, make a copy for safety, and remember to clean up `self` in instance methods:

```py
class bar:
    def foo(self, arg=None):
        kwargs = locals().copy() # {'self': <bar at 0x0000>, 'arg': None}
        kwargs.pop('self')
        baz = 'Oops'
        return another_fn(**kwargs)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `locals()` is finicky as heck, far more so than is obvious at first glance. For example, it behaves differently in a debugger. It also behaves differently in a function than it does at class or module scope, it has surprising interactions with comprehensions, it has a weird interaction with `super()`, and it usually includes closure variables, except in one particular case involving accessing closure variables in a class body.

Comment: Some, but not all, of the problems can be avoided by always copying the dict immediately, using `locals().copy()`. Particularly, the bad interaction with debuggers should be avoidable this way. However, I would still not recommend the use of `locals()`.

Comment: In the context of OP's question, those edge cases don't apply. Anything that would give OP the solution that they want will tend to be finicky as it will involve some amount of introspection.

Depending on exactly their needs (e.g. what is the context of their `foo()`), they might be better off with an approach that doesn't require explicitly creating these wrapper methods.

Comment: The debugger interaction is relevant for pretty much any code, and this isn't even the full list of weird interactions.